# A proper select all checkbox in a grid header

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, checkbox

I've inherited a new project and my jQuery skills are extremely weak. I'm looking to create a select all checkbox for a table.

---

### The background:

The table exists with a column for checkboxes. As part of the header row, there's a checkbox called "Select All" that doesn't perfectly function. You can press it and it will select all, but it will "sort" a few items (for no reason) and the box will uncheck itself when finished. This makes things difficult. Code clip:

```
<thead class="KoTableTH">
    <tr data-bind="click: sort">
        <th>
            <input type="checkbox" id="cbSelectAll1" />Select All
        </th>
        <th id="FirstName">First Name</th>
        <th id="LastName">Last Name</th>
        <th id="PhoneNumber">PhoneNumber</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
```

And a clip of jQuery:

```
$("[id*=cbSelectAll1]").live("click", function () {
    var grid = $(this).closest("table");
    $("input:checkbox", grid).each(function () {
        if (chkHeader.is(":checked")) {
            $(this).attr("checked", "checked");
            $("td", $(this).closest("tr")).addClass("selected");
        } else {
            $(this).removeAttr("checked");
            $("td", $(this).closest("tr")).removeClass("selected");
        }
    });
});
```

### Attacking a solution

So my first idea is to somehow lock down the check state at the end to no avail. Then I removed the data-bindings from the Select All for giggles and it still doesn't stick. So an unbound checkbox doesn't stay checked. I then moved on to try removing the checkbox from the table, but I can't figure out how to properly define the var grid above, as var grid = $('#checkableGrid') is not a valid definition or something as it fails silently.

### Conclusion

I think I understand the problem but no idea how to put together a solution. Putting a checkbox in a sortable header is probably not the best way to go about things, but this is my burden I've inherited.

### Update 1

While demoing some ideas, I've come across the problem of the select all checkbox works, but if at any time I sort the list through another column it unchecks some of them. Is there a way to set a column to not sort? I know this was possible using ASP Forms, but no idea how its done here. I think this would solve both problems.

### Update 2

We've come up with a stopgap solution where it waits 100 cycles and then fixes the checkbox.

```
if (chkHeader.is(":checked")) {
    count = count - 1;
    setTimeout(function () {
        $('#cbSelectAll1').prop('checked', true);
    }, 100);
} else {
    setTimeout(function () {
        $('#cbSelectAll1').prop('checked', false);
    }, 100);
}
```

While not an ideal fix it is working.

Comment: What version of jQuery are you using?

Comment: jQuery: 1.7.1. Knockout is also here, but I don't think its being used.

Answer (score 1):

Try the below code.
This is Logic for Checking checkboxes and all Checkbox.
Use the pattern for class for single checkbox => "chkSelect-'AnySignificantName'" and for all checkbox => "chkSelect-'AnySignificantName'-all" to make use of this logic.

For example, use classs "cheSelect-Grid-All" for checkbox "cbSelectAll1" of header and  "cheSelect-Grid" for the table body rows.

```
$("body").on("click", "input[type='checkbox'][class*='chkSelect-']", function () {
    var classes = $(this).attr('class').split(' ');
    var selfClassname = '', type = 'single', singleClassName = '', allClassName = '';
    if (classes.length > 0) {
        classes.forEach(function (a) {
            if (a.indexOf('chkSelect-') > -1) {
                selfClassname = a;
                return;
            }
        });
    }
    if (selfClassname !== '') {
        if ((selfClassname.match(/-/g) || []).length === 2) {
            type = 'all';
            allClassName = selfClassname;
            singleClassName = allClassName.replace("-All", "");
        }
        else {
            singleClassName = selfClassname;
            allClassName = singleClassName + "-All";
        }
        if (singleClassName !== '' && allClassName !== '') {
            if (type === "all") {
                $("." + singleClassName).prop("checked", $(this).is(":checked"));
            }
            else {
                if ($(this).is(":checked") && $("." + singleClassName).length === $("." + singleClassName + ":checked").length) {
                    $("." + allClassName).prop("checked", true);
                }
                else {
                    $("." + allClassName).prop("checked", false);
                }
            }
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Hope it helps...

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>test</title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">

    </head>
    <body>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
            for(idx=0; idx<8; idx++)
                {
                    $(".KoTableTH").append('<tr data-bind="click: sort">'
                        + '<td><input type="checkbox" class="cbSelectAll" />Item:'
                        + '</td><td>Name '+idx+'</td><td>Last Name '+idx+'</td>'
                        + '<td>PhoneNumber</td></tr>');
                }
            $("#cbSelectAll1").click(function () {
                if($("#cbSelectAll1").prop("checked") == false)
                    {
                        $(".cbSelectAll").prop("checked", false);
                    }
                else 
                {
                    $(".cbSelectAll").prop("checked", true);    
                }
            });
        });         
        </script>
        <table class="KoTableTH">
            <tr data-bind="click: sort">
                <th>
                    <input type="checkbox" id="cbSelectAll1" />Select All
                </th>
                <th id="FirstName">First Name</th>
                <th id="LastName">Last Name</th>
                <th id="PhoneNumber">PhoneNumber</th>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: When we tried that it ended up not functioning at all since the sort happened right after and reset it. I posted the stopgap in the original post for your viewing.